# Se me corrio el contenido del nav de bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap, sass

Tengo este inconveniente, se me corrio el contenido de mi navbar (links de mi web).
El nav esta hecho con boostraps y cuando comence a hacer cambios de css a sass comenzo el error.

Volvi a hacer el nav y me tira el mismo error. No se si el error viene desde el nav o de otro lado.

CSS/SASS

````
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.5rem 3.5rem;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      nav a {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  transition: var(--transition);
  nav ul {
      display: flex;
      gap: 1.9rem;
      nav ul li {
      font-weight: var(--bold-font);

  }
  nav a:hover {
  color: var(--secondary-color);
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--secondary-color);
}
}
}
}```
````

Comment: Buen día, en este caso necesitamos que nos expliques cual es el error que te arroja, y que es lo que esperas, ya que con ese código scss, no se tiene claro. y te invito a que veas la pagina [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que tengas claro como hacer una buena pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

resulta que tienes el SASS escrito incorrectamente.

Intenta usando esto:

```
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.5rem 3.5rem;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  a {
    color: var(--primary-color);
    transition: var(--transition);
    ul {
      display: flex;
      gap: 1.9rem;
      li {
        font-weight: var(--bold-font);
      }
      a:hover {
        color: var(--secondary-color);
        border-bottom: 2px solid var(--secondary-color);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Te aconsejo que verifiques en la documentación de [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation) como funciona el Nesting y la sintaxis de escritura del mismo.

Posdata: No se te olvide indentar bien tu código